# How to change the size of numbers of buildings on open street view map?

Tags: ios, swift, openstreetmap, mglmapview

[image]

Next to right side there are gray numbers: `35, 37, 39, 41, 43`. Is there a way to change its size somehow?

This is what I have in code:

```
let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.08442, longitude: 19.95825), zoomLevel: 9, animated: false)
mapView.setZoomLevel(16, animated: false)
mapView.delegate = self
self.mapView.addSubview(mapView)
```

**UPDATE:**

I have created custom style:

[image]

Then changed style of the buildings:

[image]

Then copied style url to the initializer:

```
    let url = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/kunass2/cjcubgbvq1uuq2smt3nup7nzf")
    let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: url)
```

but it still is the same. Why? What more should I do to apply that style to my map?

[image]

Comment: Did you try this https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-a-custom-style/

Comment: please, see updated question

Comment: From here: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Classes/MGLStyle.html It says `Wait until the map style has finished loading before modifying a map’s style via any of the MGLStyle instance methods below. You can use the -[MGLMapViewDelegate mapView:didFinishLoadingStyle:] or -[MGLMapViewDelegate mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:] methods as indicators that it’s safe to modify the map’s style.`

Comment: @Mukesh yes  it worked;), do you know how to change the `house_num` color or text size?

Comment: I don't know much about it but you can try creating a layer. Try this: https://www.mapbox.com/help/studio-manual-styles/#layers-list